# Nuxt 3 useFetch Post request: File object missing from server api route

Tags: post, routes, fetch, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I am trying to post a file object to my nuxt 3 api route

Problem is:

- Data from client has my file object
- Data from server returns empty object

[Screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9B2s.png)

Where did my file object go?

```js
const handleImageUpload = async (evt: Event) => {
  const target = evt.target as HTMLInputElement 
  if (target.files) {

    const file = target.files[0]

    const upload: iUpload = {
      name: file.name,
      type: file.type,
      file
    }

    console.log("data from client", upload)
    try {

      const { data, error } = await useFetch(constants.imageUploadApiUrl, {
        headers: { "Content-type": "application/json" },
        method: 'POST',
        body: upload
      })
 
      console.log("data from server", data.value)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }

  }
}
```

constants.imageUploadApiUrl (api route) has the following

```js
import { getQuery, readBody } from "h3"
import { iUpload } from "~~/helpers/interfaces"

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {

  try {
    const query = getQuery(event)
    const body = await readBody(event) as iUpload
    return { body }
  } catch (error: any) {
    return { error: error.message }
  }
})
```

iUpload interface is this

```js
export interface iUpload {
  name: string;
  type: string;
  file: File;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I eventually got it working. Meanwhile it's using supabase as it's backend (forgot to mention that).

But here are the changes I made.

#1 - I added a utility function to convert the file to base64 string

```
export const getBase64 = (file: File) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
    reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
  });
}
```

#2 - I updated the handleImageUpload function like below. The only change being in the file key

```
const handleImageUpload = async (evt: Event) => {
  const target = evt.target as HTMLInputElement

  if (target.files) {

    const fileObj = target.files[0]

    const upload: iUpload = {
      path: id(memberName(store.selected), '-'),
      name: fileObj.name,
      file: await getBase64(fileObj) as string, // <**=**
      type: fileObj.type
    }

    console.log("data from client", upload)
    try {

      const { data, error } = await useFetch(constants.imageUploadApiUrl, {
        headers: { "Content-type": "multipart/form-data" },
        method: 'POST',
        body: upload
      })

      console.log("data from server", data.value)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
}
```

#3 - Furthermore I updated the server route as follows:

```
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  try {
    const body = await readBody(event) as iUpload

    const filePath = `${body.path}/${body.name}`
    
    const res = await fetch(body.file)
    const blob = await res.blob()

    const response = await supabase.storage
      .from("pictures")
      .upload(filePath, blob, {
        contentType: body.type,
        upsert: true,
      })

    return {
      data: response.data,
      error: response.error?.message,
    }
  } catch (error: any) {
    return { error: error.message }
  }
})
```

#4 - Lastly I updated the policies on supabase storage bucket and storage object to the following:
[supabase storage policy update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lurpo.png)

Comment: How do you initiate your `supabase` object in the server route?

Comment: Nwm, I find https://supabase.nuxtjs.org/usage/services/server-supabase-client